# Lubuntu 18.04 / lxpanel 0.9.3 accidental removal of 2nd toolbar

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, lxpanel

A transparent, auto-hiding button bar was created on the left edge of the screen. It had all my most-frequently used programs on it. Was trying to add another program and accidentally clicked `"Remove "Application Launch Bar" From Panel` or `Delete This Panel`. (Dumb touchpad likes to move when finger is lifted.) Anyways it disappeared, and now another one cannot be created on the left edge. Positon Edge: Left is greyed out. **How can this be remedied?**

Answer (score 0):

Looking in `/home/username/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels` there are two files, `left` and `panel`. `panel` contains the expected settings for the bottom bar including `Plugin{}` sections for the various controls. However `left` contains just a header:

```bsh
# lxpanel <profile> config file. Manually editing is not recommended.
# Use preference dialog in lxpanel to adjust config when you can.

Global {
    edge=left
    monitor=0
    height=32
    align=center
    width=50
    transparent=1
    background=0
    tintcolor=#ffffff
    alpha=80
    iconsize=21
    widthtype=request
    autohide=1
    heightwhenhidden=1
    setpartialstrut=0
}
```

So the panel is *still there* - it just has no functions assigned to it, so is a size of 0, and nothing is displayed to right-click on. To remedy this, the `left` file could be deleted. This should allow a new one to be fully rebuilt on the left side.

A slightly easier solution is to add a `Plugin{}` section to the `left` file like so:

```bsh
# lxpanel <profile> config file. Manually editing is not recommended.
# Use preference dialog in lxpanel to adjust config when you can.

Global {
    edge=left
    monitor=0
    height=32
    align=center
    width=50
    transparent=1
    background=0
    tintcolor=#ffffff
    alpha=80
    iconsize=21
    widthtype=request
    autohide=1
    heightwhenhidden=1
    setpartialstrut=0
}
Plugin {
    type=launchbar
    Config {
        Button {
            id=menu://applications/Accessories/pcmanfm.desktop
        }
    }
}
```

Logoff and log back on, and the panel should once again be visible, albeit with only one icon on it. But it can now be right-clicked to get to the preferences. All of the desired applications will need re-added.

To prevent having to rebuild in the future, copy or backup the `/home/username/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels/left` file.